# how to stop things growing in html?

Tags: html, css

**I have a search bar and a search button but when i hover over them they grow...? What do i include in my html/css to stop this from happening?
Thanks in advance

*HTML:*

```
<form class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" />
<input class="search2" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="left: 396px; top: 159px; width: 246px;" />
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style=" padding-bottom:20px; left: 646px; top: 159px; height: 21px" />
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="_.html" />
```

*CSS:*

```
.search1
{
position: absolute;
font-family:"Arial Unicode MS";
background-color:#CCCCCC
}

.search2
{
position: absolute;
border-style:none;
font-family:"Arial Unicode MS";
color:black;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}


input:hover{
    background-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS in question.

Comment: Way more info is needed to even attempt an answer.  How about provide html/css sample that you currently have.

Comment: add some code you have used...

Comment: A minimal demo that reproduces the problem would also be quite useful, this is not behaviour that I've observed before (without explicitly specifying `input:hover, input:focus {...}` css declarations. May I suggest [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as a free, and useful, resource for hosting such demos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your mouse over (Hover) is changing the elements border style to "Solid", which is most likely causing the form to shift a few pixels around. Remove it from the Hover css and see if it works any better.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what your asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your border style is causing the problem. To avoid that you can use `outline` instead of `border`.

Comment: No, iv'e got it now, i just needed to include "border-style: none;" in search 1... thanks for your help guys!